# How to Replace Curly braces in java?

Tags: java

I am getting error when try to replace regular expression in java.

for example:

```
String h = "{hiren:}";

h=h.replaceAll(":}", ":\"\"}");
```

Please give me solution.
Thanks

Comment: If this is a literal string you are replacing, just use `.replace()`, not `.replaceAll()`. And do note that despite its name, this method _does_ replace all occurrences of its argument.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to double-escape some special characters in `Pattern`s.

`String#replaceAll` takes regular expressions, hence:

```
String h = "{hiren:}"; h=h.replaceAll(":\\}", ":\"\"}");
```

Otherwise, you can use `String#replace` with no regular expression nor escaping needed.

```
String h = "{hiren:}"; h=h.replace(":}", ":\"\"}");
```

It's a commonly mistaken assumption to believe `String#replace` will not replace all occurrences.